# Second isomorphism Therorem kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\frac{\frac{G}{N}}{\frac{H}{N}} \simeq \frac{G}{H}$

$N \subseteq H$  , N and H normal.
$$\phi :\frac{G}{N} \rightarrow \frac{G}{H}$$
$$\phi(aN)=aH$$

Why is the kernel $\frac{H}{N}$,my book has $ker(\phi)= \{aN \ |\ aH =H\}=H/N $ but that isn't very informative. I did an example, I see that it is true, but I can't see notation-wise :'(. Can anyone  explain $ker(\phi)= \{aN \ |\ aH =H\}=H/N $ in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel contains elements mapping to identity.
Identity of G/H is H.
Thus, you have aH=H.
What to you get?
a belongs to H.
The aN belongs to H/N

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now :) $aH=H$ only when $a\in H$  hence  $ker(\phi)=\{aN | a \in H\} = H/N$